# How to fetch real-time tweets using flume?

Tags: hadoop, twitter, stream, real-time, flume

Apache flume fetches tweets from previous years or months as well with my current configuration. I want to fetch current tweets. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check this github project for analyzing real time tweets in hadoop using Streaming API.

https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example

This page also includes how to setup flume, hive & oozie.

You have to install oozie and hive: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/CDH4-Installation-Guide.html

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link to get the streaming tweets to hdfs :

http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/03/analyse-tweets-using-flume-hadoop-and.html